# How to display bullets to an unordered list in Magento

Tags: html, css, magento

How to display bullets in magento? I have used disc class to that ul, but it's not displaying bullets properly (it’s displaying smaller bullets and vertically those bullets are not in the center of line exactly, font size of unordered list is bigger). I also have tried to display one image of circle as bullet, but it’s displaying image at the bottom of the text and padding or margin from bottom or top is not working on it. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this link : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/css/unordered_list_work_correctly

If you set the correct line-height of the elements inside the list it should also be vertically aligned properly.